# Как при помощи gulp-livereload сделать обновление страницы в браузере?

Tags: gulp

Как при помощи `gulp`-плагина `gulp-livereload` сделать реактивное обновления страницы в браузере в подобие тому, как работает live-reload в `Sublime Text`. Интересует решение этой задачи именно с пакетом `gulp-livereload`: чтобы можно было октрыть файл html в браузере и при изменении в редакторе кода он изменялся без обновления страницы, автоматически

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Придется еще и сервер настроить. Вот, вроде, на русском статья неплохая

http://habrahabr.ru/post/269673/

Но, я бы на вашем месте присмотрелся бы  к этому способу решения перезагрузки

https://github.com/browsersync/browser-sync